# No agrega atributo onchange a etiqueta select

Tags: jquery, select

Buen día
Tengo dos etiquetas select con opciones creados en tiempo de ejecución, los select se muestran correctamente con sus opciones, les agrego con jquery el evento onchange para que cuando se seleccione una opción diferente realice una función,

```
$("#combo1").attr('onchange', "SelectedIndex1(this.value)");
$("#combo2").attr('onchange', "SelectedIndex2(this.value)");
```

(Donde SelectedIndex1 y 2 son las funciones que quiero que realicen los combos al seleccionar un valor)
En uno de los select se realiza correctamente, pero tengo un select al que no se le agrega el evento onchange, alguna idea de por qué no me lo detecta? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad no entiendo porqué no te funciona así, nunca lo había intentado, pero lo que podrías hacer sería agregar el evento directamente, así:

```
$("#combo1").on('change', function(){SelectedIndex1(this.value)});
$("#combo2").on('change', function(){SelectedIndex2(this.value)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pero para que los añades como atributo? Simplemente hazlo como evento

```
$("#combo1").change(function(){
    var valor = $(this).val();
});

$("#combo2").change(function(){
    var valor = $(this).val();
});
```

Saludos.